# Converting rows to columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, postgresql-9.1, crosstab

i need to convert rows into columns using postgrsql
need resulSet as follows

```
monthname   2017 year(amount)    2018 year(amount) 
Jan          10                    250
feb          20                    350
mar          40                    100
```

below is my Query using crosstab function

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
$$select  
SUM(standard_loan_account_balance) as TOTAL_AMOUNT
,extract (year from mgc.transaction_date) as monthname
,extract(MONTH from mgc.transaction_date) as monthnumber

from  bankfair.tbl_das_monthly_growth_chart mgc

where  mgc.transaction_date
between (select (SELECT APP.app_today_date FROM bankfair.tbl_cmn_application_date app)+'-12 month'::interval) 
and (SELECT APP.app_today_date FROM bankfair.tbl_cmn_application_date app) group by monthnumber,monthname
order by 1,2
$$
) as ct ("TOTAL_AMOUNT" numeric,"monthnumber" double precision,"monthname" double precision)
```

i didnt get expected output

Comment: monthname    2017 year(amount) 2018 year(amount)                      Jan                      10                          250                                            feb                       20                          350                                             mar                      40                          100

Comment: A sample data set would help.  What are to actually trying to transform?

Comment: need to draw line chart example in share market so need to compare jan 2017 with reference to jan 2018 data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with a simple non-crosstab version of the query.  This should do what you want:

```
select to_char(mgc.transaction_date, 'Month') as monthname,
       sum(case when to_char(mgc.transaction_date, 'YYYY') = '2017'
                then standard_loan_account_balance else 0
           end) as slab_2017,
       sum(case when to_char(mgc.transaction_date, 'YYYY') = '2018'
                then standard_loan_account_balance else 0
           end) as slab_2018
from bankfair.tbl_das_monthly_growth_chart mgc
group by monthname, extract(month from mgc.transaction_date)
order by monh(mgc.transaction_date);
```

You can then convert this to a crosstab version, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

In your desired resultset, the columns are

```
  monthname   2017 year(amount)    2018 year(amount)
```

But in the AS clause that qualifies the result of the crosstab() call, you have put this, which seems to correspond to your non-pivoted columns:

```
   as ct ("TOTAL_AMOUNT" numeric,"monthnumber" double precision,"monthname" double precision)
```

That's wrong, because the AS clause should designate exactly the pivoted-output columns. It seems that you did not understand this aspect of  `crosstab()`, as you put the columns of the non-pivoted output.

The columns in the query passed as the first argument of crosstab also don't match. The first column needs to be the month's name, the second column the year, and the third column the amount. Finally, you need to limit the years to the ones that are hardcoded in your AS clause.